# Using a model as a template for a new model Laravel

Tags: laravel, model

Given I have a model:

```
$soda =  Soda::find(1); 
// [id = 1, name = 'Cola', containsSugar = true, bubbels = true, etc, etc,]
```

how can I save this to a new model after changing some attributes?

```
$soda->name = '7Up';
$soda->containsSuger = false;
$soda->saveAsNew() // save as a new Soda with its own id. 
// [id = 2, name = '7Up', containsSugar = false, bubbels = true, etc, etc,]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the replicate() method to create a copy of the existing model and change the attributes you wish for the new model like so:

```
 $soda = Soda::find(1)->replicate()
         ->fill(['name' => '7Up', 'containsSugar' => false])
         ->save();
```

For more information please refer to this link:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#replicating-models

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about replicating some fields from id 1 and save it to id 2 with different name

You can do it like this

```
$soda = Soda::find(1);

$newSoda = $soda->replicate();
$newSoda->name = '7Up';
$newSoda->containSugar = true;
$newSoda->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object from Soda.

```
$soda2 = new Soda([id => 2, name => '7Up', containsSugar => false, bubbels => true, etc, etc,]);
$soda2->save();
```